# Get Bash array key value according to string variable

Tags: arrays, bash

I'd like to get the value of specific key from Bash Array by the name I get from another string parameter

For example:

```
first_var="key_name01"

declare -A array
array[key_name01]="key_value 01"
array[key_name02]="key_value 02"

echo "The key name is: ${first_var} >>> Value: array[${first_var}]"
```

Is it possible and if so how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: `array[${first_var}]` -> `${array[${first_var}]}` (you're not printing the value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access an array element, you can use `${arrayname[key]}`. `key` can in turn be a `$variable`:

```
first_var="key_name01"

declare -A array
array[key_name01]="key_value 01"
array[key_name02]="key_value 02"

echo "The key name is: ${first_var} >>> Value: ${array[${first_var}]}"
```

Output:

```
The key name is: key_name01 >>> Value: key_value 01
```

Comment: And the braces are not strictly needed for the key variable: `${array[$first_var]}`